# Troubleshooting Bash script to delete files

Tags: ash

On my Synology NAS I've written a bash script that is supposed to delete the junk files that windows creates:

```
#/bin/ash
find /volume2 -type f -name "Thumbs.db" -exec rm -f {} \;
find /volume2 -type f -name "desktop.ini" -exec rm -f {} \;
#find /volume2 -type d -empty -delete \;
```

This was to the best of my knowledge working fine until I added the now commented-out line to remove the empty folders after the files are deleted. Now despite not intentionally changing anything, the script is failing with

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I'm sure I'm missing something incredibly obvious but please help, also I don't know why the last line didn't work either. I've read lots of threads on Stack with no joy.

Comment: Can't reproduce with busybox v1.31.1 ash. Which ash is this?

Comment: A possible workaround: `find /volume2 -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;`

Comment: @oguzismail good question it's on a Synology 1019+ and I cannot figure out how to answer that

Comment: @oguzismail with the files yes, but I think it would try and do it all at the same time, so the folders wouldn't delete since they'd still have the thumbs.db file in? Not sure which order the deletes would happen in

Comment: Oh, I forgot `-depth`. `find /volume2 -depth \( -type f \( -name 'Thumbs.db' -o 'desktop.ini' \) -o -type d -empty \) -delete`. With -depth it deletes files first

Comment: The trailing `\;` on the commented-out command is a syntax error.  I get different error messages for that error with `find` on different systems. None of them reports a "missing argument to -exec" but maybe that's how `find` on your NAS reports it.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, it was actually random DOS line breaks in the file and it being encoded in UTF-8 instead of ANSI. What a dumb problem